# If statement to check prop("disabled") in jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

In below code, I use a radio button to show two different `textarea` named `textA` and `textB`

```
<input onClick="optionA();" type="radio" name="button2" value="Yes" checked /><label>Option A</label>   
<input onClick="optionB();" type="radio" name="button2" value="No" /><label>Option B</label>

<div id="textA" >
<div class="input"><span><textarea  class="textarea" id="textboxA" name="textA" type="text"></textarea></span> </div>   
</div>

<div id="textB" style="display:none;">
<div class="input"><span><textarea  class="textarea" id="textboxB" name="textB" type="text"></textarea></span> </div>   
</div>

<div id="error" style="display:none;"></div>
```

If I select `textA` textarea and add data to it, it will display a message below textbox `Currently Textbox A in use` and for textB `Currently Textbox B in use`. I use below code for that:

```
function optionA()  {

$('#textA').prop("disabled",false);
$('#textA').slideDown("fast");


document.getElementById("textboxB").value="";
$('#textB').slideUp("fast");
$('#textB').prop("disabled",true);

}

function optionB()  {

$('#textB').prop("disabled",false);
$('#textB').slideDown("fast");

document.getElementById("textboxA").value="";
$('#textA').slideUp("fast");
$('#textA').prop("disabled",true);

}


$("#textboxA").keyup(function () {

if((!$("#textboxA").val()) || ($("#textA").prop("disabled"))){

$("#error").slideUp("fast");
}
else{

var message;
message ="Currently TextboxA in use";
$("#error").slideDown("fast");
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML=message;

}
});

$("#textboxB").keyup(function () {

if((!$("#textboxB").val()) || ($("#textB").prop("disabled"))){

$("#error").slideUp("fast");
}
else{

var message;
message ="Currently TextboxB in use";
$("#error").slideDown("fast");
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML=message;

}
});
```

problem facing:
If I am switching from `textA` to `textB`, the message which shows in `error div` is not hiding eventhough I have added `$("#error").slideUp("fast");` for `($("#textA").prop("disabled"))`

Here is the [**fiddle setup**](http://jsfiddle.net/anoopcr/XuKXw/) for the same issue

Comment: Your Fiddle setup is working for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I have tried with chrome and FF. what I am looking here is the message which you see when using textbox A need to hide, if I am switching to textbox B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hiding of the error div is executed in the "keyup" listener of your textareas. Simply switching the textareas, by clicking one of the radio buttons. You need to add the slideup to the functions optionA() and optionB(). For example:

```
function optionA()  {

$('#textA').prop("disabled",false);
$('#textA').slideDown("fast");

document.getElementById("textboxB").value="";
$('#textB').slideUp("fast");
$('#textB').prop("disabled",true);

$("#error").slideUp("fast");
}
```

See the changed fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xheMc/)